# Advanced search query to return only official/partner videos on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I've come across many articles (no. 14 on [this](http://www.mstoic.com/15-youtube-search-operator-improve-youtube-search/), and no. 3 on [this](http://www.labnol.org/internet/youtube-search/19261/), for example) advising the addition of

```
, partner
```

at the end of a query to return only official videos, i.e., videos from partner channels. However, such a query does not seem to work on YouTube. It just treats "partner" as a part of the query and returns results according to that. Any workarounds?

Comment: Partner doesn't really mean anything anyways – anyone monetizing is a partner now. And there is no filter for only including (or excluding, for that matter) verified channels.